# PayPal Adaptive Payments Pre-Approval

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm currently working on PayPal Adaptive Payments with Pre-Approval.
I have followed the Steps on this [link](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_preapprove_payment/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox). 
So far I'm able to make a link and Process the Pre Approval until I login to PayPal and Proceed to Authorizing the Payment.

My problem now is when it's already the Start/End Date:

```
$preapprovalRequest->startingDate = "2016-11-06";

$preapprovalRequest->endingDate = "2016-11-07";
```

The Pre-Approved Payments are not automatically Triggered on the specified Date. Is there another Step that I need to do? Or a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Upon hours of searching the Internet. I found out that you still need to trigger the Pre-Approved payments using the ***PayRequest*** Method, then you will need to add the ***preapprovalKey*** that you obtained from your PreApproved Payments.

Links that might help:

1. (https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_simple_payment/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox).
2. (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/).